# How to only show entries older than 12 months

Tags: templating, postdate

I want to build an archive template where only entries older than 12 months show up.
Is there an clean and easy way to do so? I only have strange calculations in mind.
Something like this would be nice :)

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news') if entry.postDate > 12monthsago %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were close, you can set a `postDate` param on your `craft.entries` criteria model. And the Twig filter [`date_modify`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/date_modify.html) helps you to get the DateTime from 12 months ago.

```
{% set timeAgo = now|date_modify('5:00 -12 months') %}
{% set postDateParam = '< ' ~ timeAgo|date('U') %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('news').postDate(postDateParam) %}
```

Comment: Just to understand your code:  {% set timeAgo = now|date_modify('5:00 -12 months') %} sets timeAgo to now(5 o'clock) - 12 months  or what does the 5:00 stand for?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Set the time to 5 a.m. then go back 12 months. This makes sure that the page changes once per day (at 5 a.m.). See PHP docs for all the possible relative time formats http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php