# How to show entires from past 12 months?

Tags: entry, query, queries

I need to display entries from the past 12 months. I'd like to create an entry query and set the timeframe of the entries I need.

Answer (score 2):

I used the `after` parameter in my query.

```
{% set query = craft.entries({
    after: now|date_modify('5:00 -12 months')
}).all() %}
```

I'm grabbing todays date, then modifying with the `date_modify` filter. The `5:00` string makes sure it changes at the same time everyday.

I got the usage of `date_modify` from carlcs's answer here: [How to only show entries older than 12 months](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19023/how-to-only-show-entries-older-than-12-months)